# tf.nn.conv2d does not work on my code. but tf.layer.conv2d does. want to know difference

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, convolution, mnist

When I use

```
def main_conv_nn(images, training):
    # Convolution

    convFilterShape = [3, 3, 1, 32]
    convFilterWeights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(convFilterShape, stddev=0.1))
    Layer1 = tf.nn.conv2d(images, convFilterWeights, strides= [1,1,1,1] , padding='SAME')
```

Its performance is under 20% accuracy for MNIST related code. Its performance is really bad.

however when I changed my code like this,

```
def main_conv_nn(images, training):
    # Convolution

    #convFilterShape = [3, 3, 1, 32]
    #convFilterWeights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(convFilterShape, stddev=0.1))
    #Layer1 = tf.nn.conv2d(images, convFilterWeights, strides= [1,1,1,1] , padding='SAME')

    Layer1 = tf.layers.conv2d(images, 32, [5, 5], padding= 'same')
```

it works perfectly.

WHY tf.nn.conv2d does not work ?  (there is no error but works strange)

Comment: The difference is because they use different kernel initialisers. The default for `layers.conv2d` is `variance_scaling_initializer`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to test under identical conditions first. The conv filter size is 5 x 5 in your layers example, and 3 x 3 in the first one. The 3 x 3 may be too small to capture some dependencies.

Comment: I changed the size so many times before but nothing was changed

Answer (score 0):

1. `tf.layers.conv2d` are convolution + bias
2. `tf.nn.conv2d` is convolution only